# Figure out what Tables a JOOQ Function depends on

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I was trying to dynamically add some joins to my JOOQ query only when the select statement included fields that required those tables to be part of the query.  So I need to know what tables a given Field depends on.

This is easy for `TableField`'s via `TableField.getTable()`.

It looked easy for `Function`'s too - with `Function.getArguments()` I could recursively walk the function tree until I reached all the `TableField` leaf nodes.

Sadly for me, however, `Function` class is package private.

I also didn't see any static utilities in JOOQ that could figure this out for me.

Wonder if there's a way to do this short of dirty regex against generated sql, or sneaky reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The "official" way to do this kind of SQL transformation would be by using the [`VisitListener`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-sql-transformation/) SPI and to hook into the query rendering lifecycle, collecting all distinct tables from the `SELECT` clause, adding them to the `FROM` clause via the most appropriate join.

This is the only way to get access to the arguments of the internal `Function` type, short of hacking stuff together via regexes or reflection.

#### Having said so: Be wary of doing this

You'll need to take care of any of these things (which is probably impossible):

- What happens when you self-join a table?
- How do you know whether to inner or outer join two tables?
- How do you know if you can reuse a table that is already in the `FROM` clause, or if you have to join it again?
- How do you know the "optimal" path from table A to table B if there are several possible ways to join them via foreign key?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Lukas.  The VisitorListener is something I wasn't aware of and looks like it opens up a lot of options.  All those concerns you mention are good considerations... makes sense there's no utils that provide this info.  In this case we have a fully defined queries that we just want to drop specific joins from if they are not necessary.  Something a good optimizer very well may handle anyway. (sorry, not enough posts to upvote)